# "Segmentation fault: 11" while archiving iOS application (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault

Builds for running (on the device/simulator) compile and execute properly. However, when I try to build for archiving, I get the following errors:

```
clang: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault: 11
clang: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

What are the possible reasons for this error? If it helps to know; I am using CocoaPods as a dependency manager.

Pod file is as follows :

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'PureLayout'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'QRCodeReader.swift', '~> 5.2.1'
```

Comment: It would help if you disclosed the list of the libraries being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the error. 
Error was in GoogleMaps latest version 1.12.2 & 
I changed

```
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

To

```
pod 'GoogleMaps' , '~> 1.11.1'
```

And it worked.

Check Pod dependencies with brute force,when such error occurs.